# How to link multiple objects to Queue

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I am trying to create a program in which I must add a first name, last name and age to a queue of several people which will then be sorted via quick sort via last name or age. See below for what I have currently. As I am not quite sure how to approach adding two strings and one integer into a queue.

Thank you for your help!

```
public class QueueClass {

protected static Queue<Object> Q = new LinkedList<>();

protected void addToQueue (String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    String studentInfo = (firstName + " " + lastName + " " + age);

    Q.add(studentInfo);
}

protected void printAll () {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scnr  = new Scanner (System.in);

    String userInput  = " ";
    String age        = "A";
    String lastName   = "L";

    boolean quit = false;

    while (quit == false) {
        System.out.print("\nThe list will be printed in descending order. Would you like it printed ");
        System.out.print("in order of (A)ge or (L)ast name?\n");
        userInput = scnr.next();

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(age)) {
            //SortingClass.sortByAge();
            quit = true;
            continue; }

        else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) {
            //SortingClass.sortByLastName();
            quit = true;
            continue; }

        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice."); }
    }


}

}
```

Comment: It is best to create a `Student` class and make the queue of type `Queue<Student>`. Never use `Object` as a generic parameter, that's a code smell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your big mistake is to use a String as a substitute for a valid Java class. Your Queue should not hold Strings but rather objects of a Student class, one with lastName, firstName and age (or dateOfBirth) fields. Then doing your sort on properties of the class becomes **much** easier.

so not:

```
protected static Queue<Object> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

but rather

```
protected static Queue<Student> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

Where Student has instance String fields for lastName, firstName, as well as an int for age (or again better a Date or LocalDate for birth date).

e.g.,

```
public class Student {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int age;

    public Student(String lastName, String firstName, int age) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    // hashCode and equals overrides are not essential
    // but they can be helpful if you want to see
    // if your collection contains an object of interest

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // You don't absolutely need a toString() method, but it makes printing out
    // your results a bit easier
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [lastName=" + lastName + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

This way you can sort using properties of each item in the collection, using a Comparator for instance.

Check out this link on [The String Obsession Anti-Pattern](http://cyrille.martraire.com/2010/01/the-string-obsession-anti-pattern/) for more on why you want to avoid using Strings where valid Java objects of a specific class would work better.

Side notes:

- Avoid using `<Object>` as a generic parameter as that completely obliterates any benefit from using generics.
- Avoid using static fields if you can.
- Avoid boolean statements like: `while (quit == false) {`. It is so easy to mess this up and instead type, `while (quit = false) {`, which results in totally different behavior. Much better is the more simple and elegant `while (!quit) {`